# update string on hive box value update in flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

am new to hive and flutter, so have many questions.

I need to have water intake string to update whenever a user adds drinks and the amount. I save data in a hivebox. However, I have trouble updating the string that shows the amount the user has drunk.

screen where drinks are added:

```
void addLiters(int index) async{
setState(() {
  drank += liters[index];
  percentage = (drank/goal)*100;
  needToDrink = (goal - drank);
  drank = double.parse(drank.toStringAsFixed(0));
  percentage = double.parse(percentage.toStringAsFixed(0));
  needToDrink = double.parse(needToDrink.toStringAsFixed(0));
  updateData(drinks);
});
}

subtractLitres(int index) async {
setState(() {
  drank -= liters[index];
  percentage = (drank/goal)*100;
  needToDrink = (goal - drank);
  drank = double.parse(drank.toStringAsFixed(2));
  percentage = double.parse(percentage.toStringAsFixed(0));
  needToDrink = double.parse(needToDrink.toStringAsFixed(2));
  updateData(drinks);
});
}

void updateData(List<DrinkModel> drinks) async{
var drinksBox = Hive.box('drinks_model');

setState(() {
final netDrank = drinks.fold<double>(
  0,
      (previousValue, drinks) =>
  previousValue + drinks.drank,
);

drinksBox.put('drank', netDrank);
  drinksBox.put('time', DateFormat('HH:mm').format(DateTime.now()));
});
}
```

and the widget where the drinks amount is displayed:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Hive.openBox("user_data");
  Hive.openBox('drinks_model');
 var userDataBox = Hive.box('user_data');
var drinksBox = Hive.box('drinks_model');
return AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: widget.mainScreenAnimationController,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: widget.mainScreenAnimation,
      child: Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0, 30 * (1.0 - widget.mainScreenAnimation.value), 0.0),
        child: Padding(
          child: Container(
            child: Padding(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  child: Text(
                                    drinksBox.get('drank').toString() 
                       +' '+ Languages.of(context)!.litres,
                                        )
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              child: Text(
                                Languages.of(context)!.goalWater,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              child: Text(
                                userDataBox.get('liquids').toString() 
                               + ' '+
                                Languages.of(context)!.litres,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                         ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 4, top: 2, bottom: 5),
                              child: Text(
                              Languages.of(context)!.ifExerWater,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                               ),
                            ),
                          ],
                      ),                          
                       Padding(
                            child: 
         Text(Languages.of(context)!.lastDrink + "\n" +
         drinksBox.get('time').toString(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(),
                    child: Container(
                      child: const WaveView(),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
}
```

When the app launches the value is null, after adding drinks the value becomes "0.0 l" and it does not change from that. Interestingly, time string updates to the last time the drink was drank. Is it the value update in the updateMethod? How to correctly get the sum?

Help appreciated very much! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to make an object from the one in the box,
for example

```
User user=Hive.box('users').getAt(id) as User;
```

then manipulate the data in this User object once done editing just do

```
Hive.box('users').putAt(id,user);
```